# 3d cube didn't show correctly writen by pyglet

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

Recently, I have started to learn openGL from this site => http://3dgep.com/?p=2365 
and I encounter a problem. That's I didn't get the scene as the site shows.

I post my code on this site:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from pyglet import clock, window

'''
    http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/aspect
    a dictionary site

    http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/
    opengl api reference

'''

def vector(type, *args):
    '''
        return a ctype array
        GLfloat
        GLuint
        ...
    '''
    return (type*len(args))(*args)



class model:
    def __init__(self, vertices, colorMatrix, indice):
        self.vertices = vertices
        self.colorMatrix = colorMatrix
        self.indice = indice
        self.angle = 0

    def update(self):
        self.angle += 1
        self.angle %= 360

    def draw(self):
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()

        glRotatef(self.angle, 1, 1, 0)


        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
        glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)

        glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vector(GLfloat, *self.colorMatrix))
        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vector(GLfloat, *self.vertices))

        glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, len(self.indice), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, vector(GLuint, *self.indice))


        glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY)
        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)



class world:
    def __init__(self):
        self.element = []

    def update(self, dt):
        for obj in self.element:
            obj.update()

    def addModel(self, model):
        self.element.append(model)

    def draw(self):
        for obj in self.element:
            obj.draw()


def setup():
    # look for GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)







win = window.Window(fullscreen=False, vsync=True, resizable=True, height=600, width=600)
mWorld = world()

cube = (
    1, 1, 1, #0
    -1, 1, 1, #1
    -1, -1, 1, #2
    1, -1, 1, #3
    1, 1, -1, #4
    -1, 1, -1, #5
    -1, -1, -1, #6
    1, -1, -1 #7
)


color = (
    1, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0,
    1, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0,
    0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 1,
    0, 0, 1
)

indice = (
    0, 1, 2, 3, # front face
    0, 4, 5, 1, # top face
    4, 0, 3, 7, # right face
    1, 5, 6, 2, # left face
    3, 2, 6, 7 # bottom face
    #4, 7, 6, 5  #back face
)

obj = model(cube, color, indice)
mWorld.addModel(obj)


@win.event
def on_resize(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(-10, 10, -10, 10, -10, 10)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    return pyglet.event.EVENT_HANDLED

@win.event
def on_draw():
    glClearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8)
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    mWorld.draw()


pyglet.clock.schedule(mWorld.update)
clock.set_fps_limit(30)
setup()
pyglet.app.run()
```

I think maybe I miss some important concepts so I can't get the correct result. Can anyone teach me what mistake I make? :(

Furthermore, there is something strange.

```
indice = (
    0, 1, 2, 3, # front face
    0, 4, 5, 1, # top face
    4, 0, 3, 7, # right face
    1, 5, 6, 2, # left face
    3, 2, 6, 7 # bottom face
    #4, 7, 6, 5  #back face
)
```

If I uncomment this line 
from

```
#4, 7, 6, 5 #back face
```

to

```
 4, 7, 6, 5 #back face
```

the screen will show nothing...

Answer (score 1):

0.0 well, that's weird. I have tried to translate this code into C++ and it shows correctly.
I use opengl, glut, and c++. So, I think maybe that's the issue on pyglet. Whatever,
I can go on my studying about openGL :)

Finally, I find the way how to make this code run correctly!!
change the code here

```
self.vertices = vector(GLfloat, *vertices)
self.colorMatrix = vector(GLfloat, *colorMatrix)
self.indice = vector(GLuint, *indice)
```

and

```
glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, self.colorMatrix)
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, self.vertices)
glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, len(self.indice), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, self.indice)
```

well, Is the key point garbage collection?
I think

```
self.vertices = vector(GLfloat, *vertices)
```

this way makes there is an object to reference the vector so it won't be freed when I called glDrawElements(...) and others functions which need the c-type array

Answer (score 0):

```
indice = (
 0, 1, 2, 3, # front face
 0, 4, 5, 1, # top face
 4, 0, 3, 7, # right face
 1, 5, 6, 2, # left face
 3, 2, 6, 7 # bottom face
#4, 7, 6, 5  #back face )
```

You missed the last semicolon at  `3,2,6,7[,] # bottom face`.